# "That much more so"

Tags: phrase-usage, adverbs, comparative-degree

Two lines in the movie *The Kingdom* go:

> And after speaking with Thamer, I advised withholding additional U.S. Personnel, because a large part of the religious justification for these bombs is the presence of current U.S. Personnel. More boots on Saudi soil is only gonna make an already combustible situation **that much more so**.

I am not sure what "that" does in this sentence. Without a point of reference, "that much more" doesn't make sense to me. "That much more"--how much more exactly? Why is it "that much more so", instead of *much more so*?

Answer (score 1):

It's the meaning of *that* given as no. 11 [here](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/that): "to a great extent or degree; very".

"That much more so" = "Very much more so".

Answer (score 0):

make a [something thing] that **much more so**.

**make an already sweet cake that much more so.**

It means: that much sweeter.

Whatever something already is, it will be even more that way: 
the idiom is: that much more so, where the **so** refers to the **state or quality of the thing being intensified.**

The expression has to be taken as a whole like this: that much more [sweet, dangerous, so].

after the **more**, you can have a noun, an adjective, or so (used as a deictic reference

- that much more fun
- that much funnier
- that much more so. [functions to replace the adjective]
- that much sadder.
- that much easier.

X makes a Y **that much more [Y]**

**It is not an idiom per se**. It is, however, **an idiomatic way of expressing** the fact that some characteristic **makes something that is already Y, even more Y.**

- To make an already combustible situation **even more combustible (or even more so).**

has the same semantic meaning as:

- To make an already combustible situation **that much more combustible**.
- To make a pathetic movie **even more pathetic (or even more so).**

has the same semantic meaning as:

- To make a pathetic movie **that much more so**.

These are comparative adjectival clauses that describe the adjective + noun phrase.

Comment: The meaning of "much more so" is clear. I am asking about **that**. Are you saying _that much more so_ is an idiom? I can't find it in dictionaries.

Comment: @EddieKai Alright, I will clarify.